# Find the min and max values of a continuous set of activities

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

Hi I have a data set which looks like this:

```
order   id  seq act_seq     time                    station
100     2   1   9       2015-09-02 10:18:15.000000      7
100     2   1   10      2015-09-02 10:18:22.000000      7
100     2   1   11      2015-09-02 10:26:48.000000      7
100     2   1   12      2015-09-02 10:35:20.000000      7
100     2   1   13      2015-09-02 17:32:33.000000      7
100     2   1   14      2015-09-02 17:32:39.000000      7
100     2   1   15      2015-09-02 17:32:39.000000      7
100     2   1   16      2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000      7
100     2   1   17      2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000      7
100     2   1   18      2015-09-30 04:00:13.000000      8
100     2   1   19      2015-09-30 04:00:56.000000      8
100     2   1   20      2015-09-30 07:24:00.000000      7
100     2   1   21      2015-09-30 07:24:03.000000      7
100     2   1   22      2015-09-30 07:24:06.000000      7
100     2   1   23      2015-09-30 07:24:03.000000      9
and so on..............
```

I have an order where the primary key is order,id,seq. For each order,id,seq there are a bunch of activites labelled by "act_seq" for each "station".

I want to find the min and max time for each station before they get transitioned to another station. So the output for station 7 should be:

```
order   id  seq station     min_time                    max_time
100     2   1   7           2015-09-02 10:18:15.000000  2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000
100     2   1   7           2015-09-30 07:24:00.000000  2015-09-30 07:24:06.000000
```

i.e. station 7 order was transitioned to station 8 and then after sometime from station 8 it was again transitioned to station 7, so there would be 2 records having the min and max time value .

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. Also avoid using column names which are Oracle reserve keywords, like `ORDER`.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7281ed/1)

First create a temporary column `BRK` in subquery (T2) which will determine if the station was changed, based on `lag`, as put `1` in case of a break in sequence.
The do a cumulative sum based on this new column, and then `group by` based on this `CUM_SUM` column.

```
SELECT "ORDER",
  ID,
  SEQ,
  STATION,
  MIN(TIME) AS MIN_TIME,
  MAX(TIME) AS MAX_TIME
FROM
  (SELECT T2.*,
    SUM(BRK) OVER (ORDER BY ACT_SEQ) AS CUM_SUM
  FROM
    (SELECT T1.*,
      CASE
        WHEN STATION <> NXT
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS BRK
    FROM
      ( SELECT T.*,LAG(STATION,1) OVER (ORDER BY ACT_SEQ) AS NXT FROM TABLE1 T
      ) T1
    ) T2
  )
GROUP BY "ORDER",
  ID,
  SEQ,
  STATION,
  CUM_SUM
ORDER BY "ORDER",
  ID,
  SEQ,
  STATION,
  CUM_SUM;
```

Comment: That's a neat oracle solution, unfortunately it's not working in hive.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be used to get the expected output. You need to identify as long as previous station is same and use sum to group by those rows to find out min and max time for the given row. Use Act_sq as a primary field to order by.

```
with cte as
( 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 9  as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 10:18:15.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 10 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 10:18:22.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 11 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 10:26:48.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 12 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 10:35:20.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 13 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 17:32:33.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 14 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 17:32:39.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 15 as Act_sq, '2015-09-02 17:32:39.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 16 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 17 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 18 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 04:00:13.000000' as timen, 8 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 19 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 04:00:56.000000' as timen, 8 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 20 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 07:24:00.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 21 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 07:24:03.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 22 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 07:24:06.000000' as timen, 7 as Station from dual  union all 
select 100 as Ordern, 2 as ID, 1 as Seq, 23 as Act_sq, '2015-09-30 07:24:03.000000' as timen, 9 as Station from dual  ) 




select z.Ordern, z.id, z.Seq, z.Station, z.mintime, z.maxtime  
       from (
      select t.Ordern, t.id, t.Seq, t.Station,t.samevalue  , min(t.timen) mintime, max(t.timen) maxtime   from (
      select Ordern,id,Seq, Station,timen,  sum(samestation) over  (partition by ordern order by act_sq) samevalue 
              from (
              select   Ordern,id,Seq, Station,timen,  act_sq, 
     case when lag(station,1,1) over (partition by ordern order by act_sq) = Station then 0 else  1 end samestation    from cte c) tst) t 
     join (   select Ordern,id,Seq, Station,timen, sum(samestation) over  (partition by ordern order by act_sq) samevalue 
              from (
              select    Ordern,id,Seq, Station,timen, act_sq,
     case when lag(station,1,1) over (partition by ordern order by act_sq) = Station then 0 else  1 end samestation   
      from cte) new) drv on t.Ordern = drv.Ordern and t.samevalue = drv.samevalue
      where t.Station = 7 
      group by t.Ordern, t.id, t.Seq, t.Station,t.samevalue  ) z;
```

Output:

```
ORDERN  ID  SEQ STATION MINTIME                       MAXTIME
100     2   1     7     2015-09-02 10:18:15.000000  2015-09-30 04:00:05.000000
100     2   1      7    2015-09-30 07:24:00.000000  2015-09-30 07:24:06.000000
```

Comment: Why are you joining drv and t?

Comment: Yeah now I am thinking it is not necessary I guess, can be done with one single query. Thanks @bakas

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Oracle 12c+: Pattern matching
with s (orderid, id, seq, act_seq, dtime, station) as (
select 100, 2, 1, 9 , to_date('2015-09-02 10:18:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 10, to_date('2015-09-02 10:18:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 11, to_date('2015-09-02 10:26:48', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 12, to_date('2015-09-02 10:35:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 13, to_date('2015-09-02 17:32:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 14, to_date('2015-09-02 17:32:39', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 15, to_date('2015-09-02 17:32:39', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 16, to_date('2015-09-30 04:00:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 17, to_date('2015-09-30 04:00:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 18, to_date('2015-09-30 04:00:13', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 19, to_date('2015-09-30 04:00:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 20, to_date('2015-09-30 07:24:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 21, to_date('2015-09-30 07:24:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 22, to_date('2015-09-30 07:24:06', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 7 from dual union all
select 100, 2, 1, 23, to_date('2015-09-30 07:24:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 9 from dual)
select r.*
from s
match_recognize (
partition by orderid, id, seq
order by act_seq, dtime
measures
  station as station,
  first(dtime) as dt_first,
  last (dtime) as dt_last
pattern (v+)
define v as station = first(station)
) r
order by orderid, id, seq, station;

   ORDERID         ID        SEQ    STATION DT_FIRST            DT_LAST
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
       100          2          1          7 2015-09-02 10:18:15 2015-09-30 04:00:05
       100          2          1          7 2015-09-30 07:24:00 2015-09-30 07:24:06
       100          2          1          8 2015-09-30 04:00:13 2015-09-30 04:00:56
       100          2          1          9 2015-09-30 07:24:03 2015-09-30 07:24:03
```